# How to edit .eps files?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, vector-drawings, eps

How do you deal with editing vector files in Ubuntu? What programs could you recommend if there are any?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Inkscape](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape/) is the vector graphics application of choice for most Linux users (and a lot of Windows users too).

Answer (score 2):

Try Skencil.

> Skencil is an interactive vector drawing program. It currently support
>   drawing primitives like rectangles, ellipses, Bezier curves, bitmap
>   (ppm, png, jpg, tiff etc.) and EPS images and text. All objects can be
>   rotated, scaled and sheared. Primitives can have fill and line
>   properties. A number of special effects like blend groups, text to
>   Bezier and text along a path are provided. Skencil supports an
>   unlimited undo history. Import of XFig, AI (up to version 8), WMF, CMX
>   and SVG files. Exports to EPS, AI, PDF (with reportlab) and SVG.

To install click [**Skencil** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/skencil/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>