# Opening Vector Files In Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, vector

Is there a way to open .ai, .eps and .svg files in Linux natively? Gimp can save in svg, but am not sure about the other file types

Comment: Use Inkscape to open vector files. `sudo apt-get install inkscape`

Comment: Should be possible in inkscape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit .eps files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/326577/how-to-edit-eps-files)

Comment: [What vector-image application can export in Corel or Adobe Illustrator formats?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111458/what-vector-image-application-can-export-in-corel-or-adobe-illustrator-formats)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to try Inkscape! This is a very good Vector graphics program.
[The official homepage!](https://inkscape.org/en/about/), or just use the version in our repositories.

Extract from homepage:

> Inkscape has sophisticated drawing tools with capabilities comparable to Adobe Illustrator, CorelDRAW and Xara Xtreme. It can import and export various file formats, including SVG, AI, EPS, PDF, PS and PNG.

So it should be just what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you. Am really surprised how fast it actually is in comparison with Adobe CC when using only integrated graphics!

Comment: Yes Linux is fast, ain't that why we love it!

Answer (score 3):

As a complement: to just simply view a svg file, main internet browsers can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

[rsvg-view-3](https://reposcope.com/package/librsvg2-bin) - command line viewer